# Saving TextView with onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, textview, orientation

I'm trying for hours to save & restore TextView and Buttons. It seems that I'm not able to save TextView because "outState" requires a String.

I made a TicTacToe game but I want to save all the stuffs when orientation is "landscape"

Here is a part of what I'm trying to do :

```
private Button lesBoutons[];
private Button rejouer;
private Jeu jeu;
private TextView leTexte;
private int[] tabGagne;
public boolean fini;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.PutString("savText", leTexte);
   //TextView savTexte = leTexte;
   //String phrase=leTexte.toString();
   //outState.putString("TEST", phrase);
   //leTexte.getResources();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
// leTexte.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TEST"));
}
```

How can I save this TextViews and all the buttons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `leTexte.getText()`. That will get you the text, but make sure you initialize the TextView object first.

Comment: Does the button state change? save it the same way! (button extends TextView)

Comment: you need to call also `toString()` method.